# Report Viewer in .NET8 to windows form application

Tags: reportviewer, .net-8.0, windowsformsintegration

I have a project in C#, with .NET 4 to windows form application. This project has a report made in Report Viewer.

I want to convert the project to c# . NET8. However, the report viewer report has stopped working because it can't find the package for the . NET8.

Can anyone help me? I searched the internet and found information that the report viewer only works up to .NET 4.x.

Comment: If you've found the report viewer only works up to .NET 4.x you'll need to find a .net core or standard replacement for it.